RuntimeError: (PreconditionNotMet) Cannot Load cuDNN Shared Library in Docker Container with PaddleOCR
I am currently working on an OCR task using PaddleOCR within a Docker container. I am encountering the following error when trying to execute my application:
RuntimeError: (PreconditionNotMet) Cannot load cudnn shared library. Cannot invoke method cudnnGetVersion.
[Hint: cudnn_dso_handle should not be null.] (at /paddle/paddle/phi/backends/dynload/cudnn.cc:64)
Here are the details of my setup:

Docker Image: python:3.10-slim

PaddleOCR Version: 2.8.1

Paddlepaddle-gpu Version: 2.6.1

Host System: Ubuntu - 22.04.2


Here's my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV HOME /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    poppler-utils \
    ffmpeg \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /app/.cache/paddle && chmod -R 777 /app

# Setting environment variables
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 7860

CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "7860"]

Error Details

Error Message: RuntimeError: (PreconditionNotMet) Cannot load cudnn shared library. Cannot invoke method cudnnGetVersion.[Hint: cudnn_dso_handle should not be null.] (at /paddle/paddle/phi/backends/dynload/cudnn.cc:64)

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried

Setting Environment Variables: Added ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the Dockerfile.

Questions:

What additional steps can I take to ensure that cuDNN is properly installed and accessible within the Docker container?

Are there specific Docker images recommended for using PaddleOCR with GPU support?

Could there be any other configuration issues that might be causing this problem?


Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
